# Is expected value a priori knowledge or it depends on number of experiments?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have following formula for calculation of expected value:

M(X)=np, where "n" is number of experiments and "p" is probability of success. I have fundamental problem with this formula: I always thought that expected value does NOT change with number of experiments, it's knowledge that we have in advance. For example, expected value for a six-sided dice is 3.5, and no number of experiments will change this. We can throw the dice once, five times, million times, etc, it won't change anything. We can even refuse to throw it at all, the expected value will be the same nonetheless.

I also have alternative formula that seems to share my sentiments: M(X)=Σxp

Thus: 1/6(1+2+3+4+5+6)=3.5

Now let's assume that we want to get 6, we'll count it as "success". Let's assume that I will throw the dice only once, it means n=1. Clearly, "p" (chance of success) is 1/6. M(X)=1*(1/6)=1/6.

This seems like blatant contradiction for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing two related things. The formula $np$ gives you the expected number of successes in $n$ trials. The formula $\sum xp(x)$ gives you the expected value of a single trial. These two things coincide for events with two outcomes and one trial, but in all other circumstances differ.

Consider a coin: The expected value of a single trial is obviously $1/2$. But if we flip it $1000$ times we expect to get $500$ heads.

You're also comparing apples to oranges. The expected number of successes in 1 roll of a die under your circumstances is in fact $1/6$. When you turn the die into a success/failure experiment in the way you describe, you're revaluing the numbers $1-5$ as "failure" rather than their numerical value. In your comparison, you failed to do this. If you assign a value of $0$ to $1-5$ and a value of $1$ to $6$, both formulae will yield $1/6$.

Comment: "but in all other circumstances differ." In my experience they coincided with 3 trails. "gives you the expected value of a single trial." I thought expected value is for n=∞ (or going to infinity), NOT for n=1.  "If you assign a value of 0 to 1 − 5 and a value of 1 to 6, both formulas will yield 1/6." Please, show me. I don't understand what exactly do you mean.

Comment: @user161005 They might happen to numerically coincide for larger values, but only due to a numerical coincidence. They are two conceptually different things that happen to give the same number. The expected value of the random variable is the proportion of successes, while the expected number of success is the absolute number of successes. The expected value is not related to $n\to\infty$, except that as $n\to\infty$ we expect the actually measured events to be well approximated by the EV. The expected value of the random variable is also the odds of a success after one trial

Comment: @user161005  What I mean for the die is that if you have a die with $5$ sides labeled $0$ and one side labeled $1$, the expected value of the die roll is $1/6$, just as the other formula says. When you declared $6$ a "success" you relabeled the sides of the die and then didn't take that into account in your expected value computation, hence the incorrect result.

Comment: Why 0 and 1, instead of other numbers? Like 7 and 13. Do we always need to mark "failure" as zero and "success" as 1?

Comment: @user161005 if you want these terms to have the meaning that you're used to, then yes you do need to use $0$ and $1$ this way. Otherwise you're not counting the number of successes. Remember there are units here: it's an expectation of $1/6$ successes in one die roll.

Comment: Ok, but what does expected value mean if it can change with number of experiments?

Comment: @user161005 It doesn't change with the number of experiments, the expected number of successes does. You seem to have a deeper confusion than this question. Maybe ask another question about what expected value is, or consult a statistics textbook.

Comment: "It doesn't change with the number of experiments," This is exactly what I think, but my textbook seems to think otherwise because it gives n*p as formula for calculation of expected value (AKA mathematical expectation). Does it mean that my textbook is wrong?

Comment: @user161005 As I've said, $np$ is not the formula for expected value. It's the formula for expected number of successes. My first guess is that you're misreading the textbook. But if you're not, then yes the textbook is wrong.